# PHP array is not being displayed locally but displays on live site

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I have created a plugin that gets a users Country location details including city, country and postcode.

In the plugin there are 2 functions 1 thats gets the country and then another that grabs the users country, city and postcode and outputs an array for all the users details. In a template I am trying to var_dump the data to test and on my live site it works I get this:

`string(25177) "{"700":["700","--",52.660348,-3.146407,"members"],"1517":["1517","--",53.8007554,-1.5490774,"members"],"767":["767","--",55.864237,-4.251806,"members"],"4267":["4267","--",54.978252,-1.61778,"members"],"10291":["10291","--",27.6648274,-81.5157535,"members"],"178":["178","--",52.9225301,-1.4746186,"members"],"1789":["1789","--",52.9225301,-1.4746186,"members"],"5029":["5029","--",55.953252,-3.188267,"members"],` etc etc

Here is the whole function:

```
function shiftms_userloc_get_user_location( $userid = false ) {

    if ( !$userid ) {
        if ( !bp_displayed_user_id() ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $userid = bp_displayed_user_id();
        }
    }

    $location   = '';


    $country    = bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Country&user_id=' . $userid );
    $city       = bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=City&user_id=' . $userid );
    $zip        = bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Postcode/Zip code&user_id=' . $userid );

    if( $city ) {
        $location .= $city;
        if( $zip ) {
            $location .= ' ' . $zip;
        }
    } else {
        if( $zip ) {
            $location .= $zip;
        }
    }

    if ( $country ) {
        if( $location ) {
            $location .= ', ' . $country;
        } else {
            $location .= $country;
        }
    }

    return $location;

}

function shiftms_userloc_get_locations( $format = 'json', $ajax = true ) {

    $locations = array();

    //if ( false === ( $locations = get_transient( 'shiftms_userlocations' ) ) ) {

        $args = array( 'fields' => 'ID' );
        $users = new WP_User_Query( $args );

        if ( ! empty( $users->results ) ) {
            foreach ( $users->results as $userid ) {
                $location = shiftms_userloc_get_user_location( $userid );
                if( $location ) {
                    $geo = get_user_meta( $userid,  'shiftms-geo', true );
                    if ( $geo ) {
                        $latlong = explode('/', $geo );
                        if ( is_array($latlong) && ( 2 == count( $latlong ) ) ) {
                            if ( 0 != $latlong[0] && 0 != $latlong[1] )
                                $locations[ $userid ] = array( $userid, $location, (float)$latlong[0], (float)$latlong[1], 'members' );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    //}
    $return = json_encode( $locations );

    if ( $ajax ) {
        echo $return;
        die();

    } else {

        return $return;

    }

}
```

In the local site I get this:

`string(2) "[]"`

The function that creates the array is this:

`$locations[ $userid ] = array( $userid, $location, (float)$latlong[0], (float)$latlong[1], 'members' );`

I am thinking that it is an issue with my php version but I am not sure. All the data is there because its the same db etc and when I output the current users country, city and postcode it works. It could be the type of array that I am trying to get.

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need a bit more than that to assist, What function generates the string for example, is that function returns any errors with error reporting on?

Comment: Many different things might be the cause. It can even be a server-side code bug, for example, are you sure that the array is not going out of scope, if set locally, when initialized? Provide more details. Where do you initialize the array? When do you use it?

Comment: Hey Patrick/Nick L I have added more code the actual function to be precise.